# Reactivate NSApplication and Unhide NSWindow As a Menubar App in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a menubar app, and I can deactivate the app and close the window. It still stays on the menubar next to WiFi icon. However, I have a problem reactivating the app and showing the window again when I select show menu from the menubar.

Here's the relevant code. This should be pretty simple, but definitely I'm missing something...

```
    var windows:[NSWindow] = []

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        windows = NSApplication.shared.windows
    }

    func hide() {
        for window in windows {
            window.close()
        }
        NSApplication.shared.hide(self)
        NSApplication.shared.deactivate()
    }

    func show() {
        NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
        NSApplication.shared.unhide(self)
        for window in windows {
            window.display()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This brought the window back.

```
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
NSApp.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
```

Comment: can you write the complete code ? this 2 lines instead of what inside Show() ?